# Setup kerberos delegation automatically

Tags: installation, kerberos, delegation

I have a web app that uses some backend servers (UNC, HTTP and SQL). To get this working I need to configure ServicePrincipalNames for the account running the IIS AppPool and then allow kerberos delegation to the backend services.

I know how to configure this through the "Delegation" tab of the AD Users and Computers tool.

However, the application is going to be deployed to a number of Active Directory environments. Configuring delegation manually has proved to be error prone and debugging the issues misconfiguration causes is time consuming. I'd like to create an installation script or program that can do this for me.

Does anyone know how to script or programmatically set constrained delegation within AD?

Failing that how can I script reading the allowed services for a user to validate that it has been setup correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after much digging on the internet and some testing, I've got a way forward.

The following code is c#.
Setting an SPN for a user or computer can be achieved via the setspn utility.

Alternatively, the following C# code can do the same:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+usersDN);

if (!de.Properties["servicePrincipalName"].Contains(spnString))
{
    de.Properties["servicePrincipalName"].Add(spnString);
    de.CommitChanges();
}
```

To set constrained delegation:

```
if (!de.Properties["msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo"].Contains(backendSpnString))
{
    de.Properties["msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo"].Add(backendSpnString);
    de.CommitChanges();
}
```

If the user has had non-constrained delegation enabled, you may need to turn this off before enabling constrained - but I didn't fully test this scenario.